# How to select column O - AK using getRange in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet contains list of activities, and I am currently making a calendar reminder which sends an email task reminder weekly based on current's week coverage (mon-sun), It has a `column header range of A - AL`, and `row range of 1 - 140`, What I want to accomplish is to select the `range of column O - AK` and `row 2 - 140`

here is some of my code:

```
var sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName("TaskList");
var dataArray = sheet.getRange("M2:P36" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

here is the replicate of my spreadsheet, just to show you the rows and columns, there is also the g-script source and the settings sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sp5q51YgiuUksivl97AizXU2my05bI9dkxrp_w_hozo/edit?usp=sharing

you can test run it just change the email parameter to your email to receive the output, the 2nd sheet name is "Settings"

I just want to eliminate the column "Date(Start)" and "Date(End)" in the range selection which is the columns M and N and start from column O to AK.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use `sheet.getRange("O2:AK140").getValues()`. It uses the A1 notation for spreadsheets.